# How to handle special characters in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that users enter data in and it gets entered into a mysql database. The issue is when they have entered a "%" sign or other special characters it causes problems when my website is trying to display the record. It actually causes nothing to be shown for that record when displaying results. How do I fix this?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM makerperk WHERE pid='$pid' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $makerid = $row['makerid'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $perkdescription = $row['perkdescription'];
    $image = $row['image'];
    $perktype = $row['perktype'];
    $restrictions = $row['restrictions'];
}
```

Comment: Are you using PHP to interact with mysql? Or an other programming language? And do you have a code example?

Comment: The code I am using is  $query = "SELECT * FROM makerperk WHERE pid='$pid' LIMIT 1";
 
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
 
  $makerid = $row['makerid'];
  $name = $row['name'];
  $title = $row['title'];
  $perkdescription = $row['perkdescription'];
  $image = $row['image'];
  $perktype = $row['perktype'];
  $restrictions = $row['restrictions'];

Comment: @TRacey Do not add source code in a comment which should be placed in the question itself. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] which can be run by others, which shows that the record is not being displayed. Also check the generated HTML code in your browser to see if your record data is "somewhere" in your HTML code.

Comment: Can `$pid` be a '%' and it occurs in the database?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use [PHP mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

```
/*Escape input variable:*/
$pid = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $pid);

/*Run query with escaped string:*/
$query = "SELECT * FROM makerperk WHERE pid='$pid' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $makerid = $row['makerid'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $perkdescription = $row['perkdescription'];
    $image = $row['image'];
    $perktype = $row['perktype'];
    $restrictions = $row['restrictions'];
}
```